# Is an else statement in robot framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am running the following keyword in the robot framework:

```
Welcome Page Should Be Open
    Run Keyword If    '${BROWSER}' == 'IE'    Location Should Be    ${LOGIN URL IE}
    Run Keyword If    '${BROWSER}' != 'IE'    Location Should Be    ${LOGIN URL}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Accounts    5s
    Page Should Contain    Accounts
```

Instead of having 2 Run Keyword If statements I was wondering if robot has a else statement that could be used or and OR statement that could be used?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with version 2.7.4 of robot framework you can use ELSE when calling [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If).

From [the documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If):

> Starting from Robot version 2.7.4, this keyword supports also optional
>   ELSE and ELSE IF branches. Both of these are defined in *args and must
>   use exactly format ELSE or ELSE IF, respectively. ELSE branches must
>   contain first the name of the keyword to execute and then its possible
>   arguments. ELSE IF branches must first contain a condition, like the
>   first argument to this keyword, and then the keyword to execute and
>   its possible arguments. It is possible to have ELSE branch after ELSE
>   IF and to have multiple ELSE IF branches.

For example (for clarity I'm using the pipe separated format and continuation features):

```
| | Run Keyword If | '${BROWSER}' == 'IE'
| | ... | Location should be | ${LOGIN URL IE}
| | ... | ELSE 
| | ... | Location should be | ${LOGIN_URL}
```

Comment: Why do you have ellipsis for the final three lines? Does it denote the following lines are all within the `if` statement?

Comment: @Stormie: yes, `...` denotes that the line is a continuation of the previous line. You can use this technique to make your tests more readable. See [Dividing test data to several rows](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows) in the user guide.